# Plotly Express Heatmap not working properly

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, plotly-express

I'm a newbie in Python and i need your help for solving this tricky problem..
I created an heatmap graph with seaborn in order to show Project Managers allocation on projects, and it's owrking properly.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(result_grouped[spike_cols]*100, cmap=mycmap,vmin=0, vmax=200, linewidths=.05, 
linecolor='lightgray', cbar_kws={'label': '% ore giorno'}) #"YlGnBu"
```

[image]

I tried to create the same graph with the same data with plotly express, but it seems that it doesn't represent all the data.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
spike_cols = [col for col in result_grouped.columns if '2021-' in col]
fig = px.imshow(result_grouped[spike_cols],
                #x=spike_cols,
                y=result_grouped.index,
                 width=900, height=800
               )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Sample Data
PM IT|17/02/2021|18/02/2021|19/02/2021|22/02/2021|23/02/2021|24/02/2021|25/02/2021|26/02/2021
ito|0.753503|0.753503|0.752568|0.752568|0.752568|0.614762|0.610097|0.572597
nzi|0.716667|0.716667|0.716667|0.716667|0.716667|0.716667|0.658333|0.633333

Can you please help me?

Comment: The X axis on the Seaborn side is multiplied by 100, but the plotly side is not multiplied by 100?

Comment: Multiplying by 100 on Plotly graph i have the same issue

Comment: Can you provide the sample data you used in Seaborn?

Comment: Added in the body

Comment: Please use text, not images.

Comment: I tried to write the table

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The spike_cols list was not sorted.
After sorting it works.